Proving an inequality for a set of integers
I am currently studying an advanced scheduling problem and want to prove that under certain assumptions a "symmetric" assignment is optimal. I could reduce the claim to proving the following statement:
Let $n\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$ and let $x_i\in\mathbb{Z}$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$. Let $i_{\text{max}}=|\{i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}:2\nmid x_i\}|$. Moreover, let $y_i$ be the $i$th index of an uneven entry of $x$, i.e. $y_1=\min\{j\in\{1,\ldots,n\}:2\nmid x_j\}$ and $y_{i+1}=\min\{j\in\{y_i+1,\ldots,n\}:2\nmid x_j\}$ for $i\in\{1,\ldots,i_{\text{max}}-1\}$. Then it holds that
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\left(-x_i\cdot\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{i-1}(j+1)\cdot x_j\right)-\frac{i+1}{2}x_i^2\right)+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{i_{\text{max}}}\left(\frac{y_i+1}{2}\cdot (-1)^{i_{\text{max}}-i}\right)\leq 0$.
Sadly, the formula is pretty bulky. I ran some tests in Python proving that the statement is true for $x\in\{-10,\ldots,10\}^n$ for $n\leq 5$. Moreover, the second sum is always positive unless $i_{\text{max}}=0$, so proving that the first sum is non-positive is necessary, but unfortunately not sufficient. Furthermore, even though the second sum can be bounded from above by $\frac{y_{i_{\text{max}}}+1}{2}$, this is not a feasible approach because there are cases where this would make the whole term positive, i.e. the other terms in that sum are needed. In particular, there can be no better bound than $0$ for the whole expression because there are examples which attain $0$.
Does anyone have an idea how I could approach this problem?
